If a company has a solid policy against discrimination in hiring but an individual violates that is there a remedy for the candidate?
If a job candidate has been asked questions about membership in a protected class and discriminated against on this basis by one individual acting contrary to law and company policy (the company has a reasonable and legal non-discrimination policy), what are some approaches to pursuing an equitable result without starting a formal lawsuit?

What's the jurisdiction? Age is not necessarily a protected class.

United States: California if that matters

In California age becomes protected after 40. See here. And merely asking a question may not be enough to show discrimination.

This seems more like a question for Workplace.

@Someone Your edit changed the sense of the question significantly. The original question specifically said they were not interested in legal action.

“What to do without a lawsuit” would fit better on workplace.stackexhange. The outcome depends on whether the company just has a policy or whether they actually mean it. Apart from that, the company is responsible for actions of an employee acting on behalf of the company, whether illegal discrimination or anything else.

Asking a question ≠ discrimination based on the answer
All businesses ask questions about age; at a minimum, they need your date of birth to confirm you are who you say you are and to distinguish you from all the other "John Smith" applicants. Even if they didn't, your educational and job record would allow anyone to guess your age within five years or so.
However, knowing your age and discriminating based on your age are not the same thing. You proving the former in no way proves the latter.

Fair enough [in general].  I would add that in this case the candidate was recognized by the interviewers to be the most technically qualified.  Multiple questions centered on age.  All questions [age related or not] were answered in any case thoroughly and well [that subjective statement can  be justified].  Then what is the justification for a different selection.

@WestCoastProjects "the candidate was the most technically qualified, but the way they interviewed made us feel that they'd be a pain in the ass to work with" - no illegal discrimination there.

"He" answered questions with respect and thoroughly.  You're suggesting a "he said she said".   So then do you have the courage to stand up and say "where/when can the line be drawn?"    Maybe provide some thoughts on how that is not a simple get out of jail free reaction.

@WestCoastProjects that is indeed a problem. That's why unlawful discrimination cases, unless they are blatant or the defendant leaves a clear evidence trail, are really, really hard to prove.

@DaleM. OK that feedback is helpful.

@WestCoastProjects - apparently you are under the impression that determining the 'best' candidate to make a job offer to is a simple procedural evaluation process with definite metrics that anyone can apply. There are always many shades of grey.

@JonCuster.  I've been around the block having participated in hundreds of interviews (either side of the table) and am not oversimplifying this (including considering that non technical considerations are also quite important).  The behavior and questions of one of the interviewers during the entire interview was strange.  I don't look at just one question or if they're just somewhat off the mark: it was essentially all questions and being well wide. I was actually able to establish an indirect dialogue with the company and am satisfied with the clarifications and the process.

ontario
Discrimination by one employee is enough. It does not need to be widespread. Many discrimination claims only allege a single instance by a single employee.
Remedies can include:

compensation
restitution
anything that furthers compliance with the act, including any direction with respect to future actions

See the Ontario Human Rights Code.
